# React Naitve shows only one View

Tags: javascript, reactjs, native

in my app on my homescreen I am rendering a ListList with my items. Now I wanted to add a little info text above it. But it only shows my text and skips(?) my FlatList. Could anyone help me and explain me this behaviour?

If I have my text component in my file it only shows the text. If I only use FlatList it shows correctly my list with my data. But if I try to combine both, it only shows one component. Same thing when I use only FlatList and wrap it inside of View then I get only a white blank screen.

```
const JobsScreen = (props) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [isRefreshing, setIsRefreshing] = useState(false);

  const allJobs = useSelector((state) => state.job.availableJobs);

  const loadJobs = useCallback(async () => {
    setIsRefreshing(true);

    try {
      await dispatch(jobActions.fetchAllJobs());
    } catch (err) {}

    setIsRefreshing(false);
  }, [dispatch]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    loadJobs().then(() => {
      setIsLoading(false);
    });
  }, [dispatch, loadJobs]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const willFocusSub = props.navigation.addListener("willFocus", loadJobs);

    return () => {
      willFocusSub.remove();
    };
  }, [dispatch, loadJobs]);

  if (isLoading) {
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          justifyContent: "center",
          alignItems: "center",
          backgroundColor: "#2f3640",
        }}
      >
        <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#fff" animating />
      </View>
    );
  }

  return (
    <View>
      <FlatList
        data={allJobs}
        onRefresh={loadJobs}
        refreshing={isRefreshing}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
        style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "#1a191e" }}
        renderItem={(itemData) => (
          <JobItem
            description={itemData.item.description}
            titel={itemData.item.titel}
            fname={itemData.item.fname}
            cover={itemData.item.cover}
            genre={itemData.item.genre}
            year={itemData.item.year}
            id={itemData.item.id}

            //           friend={itemData.item.friend}
          />
        )}
      />
    </View>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it by myself.

```
 <View style={{ height: "100%" }}>
```

solved it.

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
<View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
```